# How to build netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.32.Final-linux-x86_64.jar?

Tags: java, linux, netty, x86-64, epoll

I am using native epoll transport in netty and was able to download netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.32.jar from the repository.

However I also need netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.32.Final-linux-x86_64.jar but not unable to find it anywhere. Please let me know where to download this jar, or how to build it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in following link:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.0.32.Final/