# Jar searching for Archive by attaching the name linux-x86_64

Tags: ant, netty, ivy, reactor-netty

I am using ant as a build tool and using Ivy for dependency management.

```
<dependency conf="compile->master;runtime->default" org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="5.1.6.RELEASE"/>
<dependency conf="compile->master;runtime->default" org="io.projectreactor.netty" name="reactor-netty" rev="0.9.6.RELEASE"/>
```

Now when I give ant build it is failing to find the jar, the problem is it is attaching **linux-x86_64**.
It is searching for below jar

http://companyRepo:8081/nexus/content/groups/OfficialDevelopment/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.48.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.48.Final-linux-x86_64.jar

Why is it searching for linux-x86_64 ?

I searched and found similar issues but not sure on the solution.

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7101

[How to build netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.32.Final-linux-x86_64.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360154/how-to-build-netty-transport-native-epoll-4-0-32-final-linux-x86-64-jar)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about ant but its basically the "classifier". Please check the ant /ivy documentation on how you can specify a classifier

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Ivy user, but I believe you need to add a dependency for **netty-transport-native-epoll** with a nested artifact for the classified native libraries. Something like this:

```
<dependency org="io.netty" name="netty-transport-native-epoll" rev="4.1.48.Final">
   <artifact name="netty-transport-native-epoll"/>
   <artifact name="netty-transport-native-epoll" e:classifier="linux-x86_64"/>
</dependency>
```

I usually use https://mvnrepository.com/ to figure out different dependency syntaxes, and the Ivy descriptors are included, but it seems that, unlike Nexus et. al., it does not support searching by classifier.